# using threads in mod_perl

Tags: multithreading, perl, mod-perl2

I want to use threads with mod_perl,

as a sample I use following script:

```pl
use strict;
use warnings;
use threads;

sub doOperation{
        my $vr = $_[0];
        my $i = 0;
        while($i < 10000000){
                $i++
        }
        print "Thread done! var1 = $vr\n";
        threads->exit();
}

my @thr;
$thr[0] = threads->create(\&doOperation,5);
$thr[1] = threads->create(\&doOperation,6);

foreach(@thr){ $_->join(); }
```

I works smooth using CLI:

```
# perl multithr.pl
Thread done! var1 = 6
Thread done! var1 = 5
```

However if run it through Apache mod_perl module it causes Segmentation fault error.

My Environment:

```
CentOS-6.5 x86_64
httpd-2.2.15
mod_perl-2.0.4
```

Answer (score 0):

threads->exit();

This statement raised Segmentation fault error. Exit thread properly!